# How to remove duplicate entries in Visual Studio Selector?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual C++ Express 2010. Weird thing, when I start *.sln file with "Microsoft Visual Studio Version Selector" (dblclick in explorer for example), I get 2 lines for each installed product.

Meaning duplicated (2010 and 10 are the same)

- Visual C++ 2010
- Visual C++ 10

How to remove one of them?

[image: Duplicate entries in VS Selector]

Screenshot of "About" dialog.

[image: Visual C++ Express version]

Comment: Do you have any of the VS2010 Betas installed on your computer?

Comment: No I don't. Screenshot of "About" added. Express was installed from predownloaded ISO, not from "web".  Same problem on "fresh" installation (Win8 + Express 2010 + WinSDK7.1).

Answer (score 2):

The values are probably in the registry. You should be able to figure out where the settings on with the help of Sysinternal's Process Monitor.

The Visual Studio Launcher is called VSLauncher.exe. If you filter for registry operations that are performed by that executable, it shouldn't be too hard to find.

[image].

I have made a [github repo](https://github.com/zippy1981/VSLauncheer-Procmon) with the filter and the procmon events for your reference. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the logs! As far as I remember, I was trying ProcMon, but had not found the reason. Going to ProcMon again to compare...